# How to save a function result that is always the same to reduce time

Tags: python, pickle

I have a function that takes about a minute to be executed, and I want to save the result and somehow check if I have the result stored to avoid executing the whole function everytime.
I was told that the pickle library can help me, but I've never used it, and I don't know if it can be helpful in this situation.

The result format is two lists

```
x=[27.93444444444444, 27.345321428571427, 27.16951351351352, 26.750275, 26.33651724137932, 26.330903225806452, 26.27517647058824, 26.12369444444444, 25.420257142857142, 25.349783783783785, 24.932657142857146, 24.839000000000002, 24.69474193548387, 24.62828125, ...]
y=['MSC', 'OCO', 'MAZ', 'GIO', 'RAI', 'STR', 'TSU', 'GAS', 'RUS', 'VET', 'ALO', 'HAM', 'SAI', 'RIC', ...]
```

Edit:
I want to save the result in a file and check if the result is stored to get it from the file instead of executing the function

Comment: so, what do you want to check? give us an example

Comment: Google "memoization". Pickle is for saving data to a file.

Comment: You want [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: So you're running your program multiple separate times? Not just calling the function multiple times within the same single run of your program?

Comment: Do you want to get the same result from multiple calls within your current execution or do you want to get the same result across multiple executions of your program?

Comment: Make a dict of pre-calsulated pairs {"1": (x, y), "2": (xx, yy),...}  conditions : results. I guess check if all your conditions are in the list of a conditions set from the pre-calsulated pair should be much faster. And you can use both Pickle serilized datafile  or a simple data.py  with from data import pre_calculated_dict

Comment: There are plenty of options to store result/data between separate executions of your code. `pickle` shouldn't be your first choice.

Comment: So I have a GUI that has a button with a function connected to it. Depending on a variable (year) the function has 3 possible outputs. I want to execute the function once and then store the result to avoid waiting the execution time.

Comment: @buran What should be the first choice?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I am sure you know that this will depend on a lot of factors and OP didn't share enough information to make even a opinionated suggestion. However `pickle` is not secure and big red warning is  displayed in the docs for a reason. That's why I said it shouldn't be the first choice. And based on the additional info provided by OP, most likelty they don't need to store the result on disk at all.

Comment: @buran Hmm... I actually wonder now: Probably at least almost always, people only unpickle data they themselves previously pickled. Is that unsafe? Or is it only unsafe to unpickle pickle-data produced by someone else?

Comment: @KellyBundy, can you assure that data you pickled have not been tempered with or replaced? That's why the suggestion is to sign them. It's just not worth the hassle when you can use e.g. JSON.

Comment: @buran I'd say at least in my cases, yes I'm sure. Unless someone else was able to temper with data on my computer. In which case I've lost already anyway and they don't need to exploit my use of pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is fine. Or even [hdf5](https://www.h5py.org/). But you might also consider [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). It's designed for reading and writing config files. It's built into the standard library and it's pretty easy to use.

To write your file:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['DEFAULT'] = {'x': [27.93444444444444, 27.345321428571427, 27.16951351351352, 26.750275, 26.33651724137932, 26.330903225806452, 26.27517647058824, 26.12369444444444, 25.420257142857142, 25.349783783783785, 24.932657142857146, 24.839000000000002, 24.69474193548387, 24.62828125],
                     'y': ['MSC', 'OCO', 'MAZ', 'GIO', 'RAI', 'STR', 'TSU', 'GAS', 'RUS', 'VET', 'ALO', 'HAM', 'SAI', 'RIC']
                     }
with open('myfile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

and the file will look like:

```
[DEFAULT]
x = [27.93444444444444, 27.345321428571427, 27.16951351351352, 26.750275, 26.33651724137932, 26.330903225806452, 26.27517647058824, 26.12369444444444, 25.420257142857142, 25.349783783783785, 24.932657142857146, 24.839000000000002, 24.69474193548387, 24.62828125]
y = ['MSC', 'OCO', 'MAZ', 'GIO', 'RAI', 'STR', 'TSU', 'GAS', 'RUS', 'VET', 'ALO', 'HAM', 'SAI', 'RIC']
```

To read the values back:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('myfile.ini')
x = config['DEFAULT']['x']
y = config['DEFAULT']['y']

print(x)
print(y)
```

which has output:

```
[27.93444444444444, 27.345321428571427, 27.16951351351352, 26.750275, 26.33651724137932, 26.330903225806452, 26.27517647058824, 26.12369444444444, 25.420257142857142, 25.349783783783785, 24.932657142857146, 24.839000000000002, 24.69474193548387, 24.62828125]
['MSC', 'OCO', 'MAZ', 'GIO', 'RAI', 'STR', 'TSU', 'GAS', 'RUS', 'VET', 'ALO', 'HAM', 'SAI', 'RIC']
```

There's a third party library similar to ConfigParser called [ConfigObj](https://github.com/DiffSK/configobj) that is more powerful and marginally easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a decorator to wrap your existing function, so that each time you call it with the same parameters, it bypasses the function call and returns the existing value.

```py
from functools import wraps

def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def func(x, y, z):
    #long expensive calculation
    return x+y+z
```

Comment: This is `functools.lru_cache` except with fewer features.

Comment: @kindall Most important missing feature: The ability to call `func` at all :-)

Comment: didn't even notice that... fixed it